# how to check the implementation of struct _ when using gdbus-codegen

Tags: linux, glib, gdbus

in this repository https://github.com/chiehmin/gdbus_test/blob/master/minminbus.h

```
#define MIN_MIN_BUS_TYPE_GDBUS (min_min_bus_gdbus_get_type ())
#define MIN_MIN_BUS_GDBUS(o) (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((o), MIN_MIN_BUS_TYPE_GDBUS, MinMinBusGDBUS))
#define MIN_MIN_BUS_IS_GDBUS(o) (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE ((o), MIN_MIN_BUS_TYPE_GDBUS))
#define MIN_MIN_BUS_GDBUS_GET_IFACE(o) (G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_INTERFACE ((o), MIN_MIN_BUS_TYPE_GDBUS, MinMinBusGDBUSIface))

struct _MinMinBusGDBUS;
typedef struct _MinMinBusGDBUS MinMinBusGDBUS;
typedef struct _MinMinBusGDBUSIface MinMinBusGDBUSIface;
```

i really want to know the composition of the _MinMinBusGDBUS, but i can't find implementation of the _MinMinBusGDBUS, and i want to know about gdbus step by step..

please give me some help about this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a definition of a `struct _MinMinBusGDBUS` because `MinMinBusGDBUS` is a GObject interface, rather than a class. Just like Java interfaces vs classes, it cannot have a concrete instance unless it’s implemented by another class, which would provide its own instance struct.

Comment: aha it was very  useless thing  that i kept finding the definition...thanks Philip Withnall!!! :)